# How to prevent Ubuntu from mounting a partition it finds?

Tags: mount, filesystem, fstab, automount

Adding a static `fstab` record for a particular partition effectively prevents automatic mounting logic from handling it and this works great when I want the partition to actually be mounted (in a place I choose). But what if I want it to be ignored as if it just were not there? But I don't seek to hide it entirely. I don't mind if `gparted` can see it and a manual mount command is able to access it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partitions will effectively be prevented from mounting by using the **[noauto](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/mount)** option in their `/etc/fstab` entry.

---

**Example:**

The following line will hide my `ntfs` partition `/dev/sdb2` from appearing in Nautilus, from mounting with `sudo mount -a`, or on system boot:

```
UUID=87654321FFFFFFFF /mnt ntfs rw,suid,dev,exec,noauto,users,async 0 0
```

Now if we need to mount this partition then the following command will mount it to `/mnt` (or any other mount point we had defined in our fstab):

```
mount /dev/sdb2
```

In case we only want root to be able to mount this partition just leave out the option `users` and replace it by `nouser`.

Comment: This is a good one.

Comment: But if a partition is not mounted, it will be shown in nautilus.

Comment: @Pilot6: not on my test sytem - only those partitions that did not have an fstab entry showed up in Nautilus but not those with `noauto` option.

Comment: I did not test it, but I suspected that it could be the case. Then it is a perfect solution,

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite get what you are trying to achieve, but here is a  suggestion.

You can setup `/etc/fstab` to mount a partition to a hidden directory with no read permissions. That will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have two data partitions that I mount at boot with `/etc/fstab`. However, I dual boot with Fedora. I do not want that to mount on boot (or Xubuntu from Fedora). Therefore, I just use udisks to mount those when I need to ('X' indicates partition number).

```
sudo udisks --mount /dev/sdX
```

You can then set an alias or a keyboard shortcut for the command if preferred. I like Takkat's solution above too, but this is another option.